# Array of files and folders in current directory java and valid string

Tags: java, arrays, string, scanning

I get an array with all of the files and folders in the current directory of the jar file.

Next step, to get a string input from the user (name of file or folder...),
and search that string in the array. Something like `array.indexOf`, and if it exists, print the full path of the file.

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
System.out.println("Current working directory : " + workingDir);

System.out.println("Give Me The Name Of The File You Search In current Directory");
String specific = in.nextLine();

File f = new File(workingDir);
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));

System.out.println(files);

if (files.contains(specific)) {
System.out.println("File exsist");
}
```

How do I do the next step?

** solved. thank you

Comment: So shouldn't you use files.contains(specific) ? Not entirely sure what your question is. How to search for a string in array of strings, or how to print full filepath?

Comment: both. first to search for a string, and then print the full filepath that include the string in array.

Comment: You should accept the answer that helped you by clicking the big check mark beside the answer.

Answer (score 0):

So your code should be something like this where you compare the names if the strings :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++){
   File file = files.get(i);
   if (file.getName().contains("yourFileName")){
      System.out.println("File Exists");
    } 
 }
```

Comment: edit my question. when i try this its not prompt the "file exists", even if its true.

Comment: @EyalCohen Ok. My bad. Try this solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
if(files.get(x).getName().contains(fileString))
```

Or to answer completely:

```
  for(File file : files){
  if(file.getName().contains(specific)){
      // process file
      System.out.println("Full filepath is " + workingDir + "/" + specific);
  }
}
```

EDIT:

To also check if it has never been found:

```
  boolean wasFound = false;
  for(File file : files){
  if(file.getName().contains(specific)){
      // process file
      System.out.println("Full filepath is " + workingDir + "/" + specific);
      wasFound = true;
  }
}

   if (!wasFound) {
     // File was not found, show an error
   }
```

Comment: hey and thanx. whet the var x mean? just for the understanding

Comment: thank you very much, its get almost evrey thing. but, in the else statment i try to print an error massage, and its print the massage for evrey item in the array. how can i return false until its true, or the scan is end without get match to the string and then push the error massage?

Comment: set a boolean value at the start and if it's value never changes it means you have never found the file. I'll edit for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the full filepath of the file who's name is being stored in the "specific" string then here's what you should do.

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.out.println("Current working directory : " + workingDir);

    System.out.println("Give Me The Name Of The File You Search In current Directory");
    String specific = in.nextLine();

    File f = new File(workingDir);
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(f.listFiles()));

    System.out.println(files);

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.getName().equals(specific)) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> First to search for a string

You can create a file object with the input, using the complete path since the `ArrayList files` contains the full path of the files. Something like:

```
File toCompare = new File(workingDir+System.getProperty("file.separator")+specific);
```

And then see if it exists in the list:

```
if(files.contains(toCompare))
```

> And then to print the full filepath that include the string in array
>   Then print the complete path:

```
    System.out.println(toCompare);
```

Otherwise say not found:

```
else
    System.out.println("not found");
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
File toCompare = new File(workingDir+System.getProperty("file.separator")+specific);
if(files.contains(toCompare))
    System.out.println(toCompare);
else
    System.out.println("not found");
```

Comment: thank you very much good man. excecly what i was looking for.